# Identify this set as a group, monoid, or semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

The set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ with the composition law $m\cdot n=mn^2.$

What I don't get is how we can identify this set with any of the three possibilities because the composition law isn't associative: $3 \cdot 8 = 3 *  8^2 \neq 8 * 3^2 = 8 \cdot 3$. I view the composition rule as saying "multiply the left hand number with the square of the right hand number"

Comment: Your counterexample is for **commutativity**, not **associativity**. (That said, this isn't associative either since $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=ab^2c^2$ but $a\cdot (b\cdot c)=ab^2c^4$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah that's my bad. How can we identify this set with a group, monoid, or semigroup then, if all structures require associativity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example means that is not commutative rather than not associative. Nevertheless, you are right in saying it is not associative:

$(2 \circ3)\circ 4 = (2*3^2) \circ 4 = 2*3^2 *4^2 = 288  $, whereas $2 \circ (3\circ 4) = 2 \circ (3*4^2)= 2*(3*4^2)^2 = 4608$, which means that it is none of the above. It is merely a magma.